# Typescript Angular ngIf reverse

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this object `isArchiveValid`  and its being set base on the count of relatedTemplates. On my view I have a message that I want to display and I have a button I want to hide. Is there a way I can use the same object isArchiveValid for both or do I need another object that is doing the reverse ?

ts class

```
 showDialog() {

        console.log(this.relatedTemplates.count);

        this.isArchiveValid = this.relatedTemplates.count == 0 ? true : false;
        console.log(this.isArchiveValid);
        this.$modalDialogContainer.modal("show");
    }
```

view

```
 <div class="row agent-form-row" *ngIf=isArchiveValid>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <div class="text-danger">
            This Agent is being used by Templates and can't be archived
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf=isArchiveValid  (click)="onArchiveAgent()">Archive</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use logical not `!` or if/else: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

```
<div class="row agent-form-row" *ngIf="isArchiveValid">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <div class="text-danger">
        This Agent is being used by Templates and can't be archived
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="!isArchiveValid"  (click)="onArchiveAgent()">Archive</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `isArchiveValid` is a variable and not a function. If you want to hide the text when the archive is valid you can use `!isArchiveValid`. This means that the error will only show if `isArchiveValid` is false.

Answer (score 0):

there is a `ngIfElse` input to ngIf directive. To use it, wrap the else piece in the template and pass it to the `else` piece of `ngIf` directive like this:

```
 <div class="row agent-form-row" *ngIf="isArchiveValid; else archiveBtnTemplate">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <div class="text-danger">
            This Agent is being used by Templates and can't be archived
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<ng-template #archiveBtnTemplate>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf=isArchiveValid  
  (click)="onArchiveAgent()">Archive</button>
</ng-template>
```